# Duplicate the Database of Sage Server on PgAdmin

Tags: database, pgadmin, sage-erp

Have you any idea about how to  duplicate the Database of Sage Server on PgAdmin? 
I did this with SSMS and it works but i want to get it with PgAdmin.

Otherwise, can we add a microsoft database to pgadmin?

Comment: It's SAGE100. An application for entreprise management and it uses serverSQL as database

Comment: Then please use [tag:sage-erp], the generic tag for products by The Sage Group Plc (including SageOne, Sage50, Sage100, Sage200, Sage300...) and remove the [tag:sage] tag, which is for SageMath.